# Why do I need two inits when implementing a custom UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am currently learning iOS and one part that I find confusing is having mandatory initializations for things like UIButtons. Here is an example below.

```
import UIKit

class CustomButton: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }
    
    init(backgroundColor: UIColor, title: String) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        configure()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func configure() {
        //code that configures my button
    }
}
```

So here I am creating a custom for my app. I have noticed I needed two inits.

```
 override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }
```

and

```
    init(backgroundColor: UIColor, title: String) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        configure()
    }
```

I always assumed the first init was to actually initialize the **button**. It is the equivalent of me going to apple and saying "Hey, I want to be able to create a button based off of everything that UIButton has".

However, it seems that I have to have another init if I actually want to be able to customize the button. My second init is me pretty much saying "Hey, I want to be able to create a button with certain attributes such as a background color and a title". I find this kinda weird... Why do I need a separate initializer to do this? Why do I need to set the super.init(frame: .zero)? In a way, why do I even need a super.init in my custom init? Can't I pack everything into the first init?

Just in case, I was rambling. I find it confusing that we have to use two inits. I would think that we could just use one and pack everything into it. To me these two inits feel completely different and serve no purpose for each other. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually you don't need to override `init(frame` but an UI element needs always two initializers depending on if it's going to be initialized by Interface Builder which calls `init(coder` or in code.

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html - particularly read about designated initialisers and inheritance

Comment: For ability instance object from Interface Builder, because you can't init object from interface builder with custom parameters